# Why did "status" in "presence" stop working for me?

Tags: javascript

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')**

```
/** @format */

const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');


module.exports = new Command({
    name: "hello",
    description: "Hello!",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        message.reply("Hello!");
        console.log(message.guild.members)
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({dynamic:`gif`}))
            .setTitle('**Информация о сервере:**')
            .setColor(0x202020)
            .addField(`${message.guild.name}:`, `Владелец: <@${message.guild.ownerId}>`, false)
            .addField(`Регион сервера:`, `Дата создания сервера: ${message.guild.createdAt.toLocaleString()}`, true)
            .addField(`Количество участников: ${message.guild.memberCount}`, `В сети: ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status !== "offline").size}\nНе в сети: ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == "offline").size}`, false)
            .addField("⠀", `*Связь с создателем — [telegram](https://t.me/FlipSize)*`)
            message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });

    }
});
```

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.